# Linq - Limit number of results by same value of a field

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, oracle11g

I have a problem with a creation of a Linq to Entities (Oracle 11g) request. Here is the 
I have a table TREATMENT with three column (simplified version) : ID, STATE and APPLICATION. Here is a sample :

```
ID  STATE   APPLICATION
1   A       MAJ
2   A       FLUX
3   A       FLUX
4   R       REF
5   A       REF
```

Now, my objectives are to retrieve the data with theses rules:

- State must be A (added)
- Number of rows per application below a max value
- The max value is minored b the number of row with State = R (per application)

Exemple : If the max value is 1, I must retrieve  row 1 and 2. (Can't retrieve row 5 since there is already a REF with state R (the row 4))

I manage to retrieve all the row when the number of R is equal or greater than the max value, but I don't see how to limit my number of result in order to respect the max value.

Here is the request :

```
using (Entities bdd = new Entities())
{
    var treatments = from trt in bdd.TREATMENT
                     let app = from t in bdd.TREATMENT
                               where t.STATE == "R"
                               group t by t.APPLICATION into grouped
                               where grouped.Count() >= maxPerApplication
                               select grouped.Key
                     where trt.STATE == "A" && !app.Contains(trt.APPLICATION)
                     orderby trt.ID
                     select new TreatmentDto()
                     {
                         Id = trt.ID
                     };

    result = treatments.ToList();
}
```

In SQL, I would use an inner request and a ROWNUM to limit the number of result, but I don't see how to do it. The only solution I see is to do the request in two parts, but I want to avoid this to maintain the consistency of the information.

Comment: Did you look at `Take(rowCount)`?

Comment: I saw that, but I don't really see how to make a `Take` by application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, not sure if it's the best, but it works :

```
using (Entities bdd = new Entities())
{
    from trt in bdd.TREATMENT
    where trt.STATE == "A" &&
    (from trt2 in bdd.TREATMENT
    where trt2.STATE == "A" && trt2.APPLICATION == trt.APPLICATION && trt2.ID <= trt.ID
    select trt2).Count() <= maxPerApplication - (from appp in bdd.TREATMENT
                                                 where appp.STATE == "R" 
                                                 && appp.APPLICATION.Equals(trt.APPLICATION) 
                                                 select appp).Count()
    select new TreatmentDto()
    {
     Id = trt.ID
    };

    result = treatments.ToList();
}
```